# unable to run a grunt command

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am using this in `gruntfile.js`.

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

  grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
        sass: {
             options: {
                 sourceMap: true
             },
             dist: {
                 files: {
                     'css': 'scss/*.scss'
                 }
             }
         }
  });


grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');  // Load tasks
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass']); // Register Task as Default
}
```

But it is giving me an error when I run this command

```
Task "sass" not found
```

Please tell me where am i doing it wrong.

Comment: You need to install sass on ur machine? It sass installed?

Comment: @Harkirat sorry it is grunt not gulp. yes i have sass installed

Comment: I think you missed adding grunt.loadNpmTask('sass')

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing task registration in the beginning of gruntfile

`require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);`

The documentation for using grunt-sass can be found at https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass/blob/master/readme.md

Comment: In the beginning of the grunt file

Comment: But you already installed grunt-contrib-sass, right?(npm install grunt-contrib-sass --save-dev)

Comment: yeah i installed using  npm install --save-dev grunt-sass

Comment: is it different from the contrib install version?

Comment: Yes it is a different package. In this case you need to add at beginning at file : require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

Comment: Actually they are different packages and this is what their official documentation use https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass/blob/master/readme.md

Comment: ok i also added this require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt); but dosen't work

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sass i am following this document it nowhere it says how to add a package

Comment: Actually they do in the usage section. And they ask also to install: npm install --save-dev load-grunt-tasks

Comment: Can you now submit your current gruntfile

Comment: no task is running. i used gunt default from CLI it says the same. no default task.

Comment: You didn't add require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt); ?